# How to center a ListView elements in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a coursel with the active dots indicator.

like the one on Instagram I'd like to create a listview when the number of dots grows.
[image]

When they are too many you probably wont have an issue of layout but if they are like 2 then I'd like to keep them centered.

I'd also like to know how to shrink the ones on the edges to indicate continuity if possible I can't quite figure out how you can achieve that.

I tried to get the active and center the active dot with something like this

```
_scrollTo(int index) {
    // get the screen width. This is used to check if we have an element off screen
    RenderBox tabsContainer =
        _tabsContainerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    double screenWidth = tabsContainer.size.width;

    // get the button we want to scroll to
    RenderBox renderBox = _tabKeys[index].currentContext.findRenderObject();
    // get its size
    double size = renderBox.size.width;
    // and position
    double position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;

    print(position);
    // this is how much the button is away from the center of the screen and how much we must scroll to get it into place
    double offset = (position + size / 2) - screenWidth / 2;

    // if the button is to the left of the middle
    if (offset < 0) {
      // get the first button
      renderBox = _tabKeys[0].currentContext.findRenderObject();
      // get the position of the first button of the TabBar
      position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset(-20.0, 0.0)).dx;

      // if the offset pulls the first button away from the left side, we limit that movement so the first button is stuck to the left side
      if (position > offset) offset = position;
    } else {
      // if the button is to the right of the middle

      // get the last button
      renderBox = _tabKeys.last.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      // get its position
      position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dx;
      // and size
      size = renderBox.size.width;

      // if the last button doesn't reach the right side, use it's right side as the limit of the screen for the TabBar
      if (position + size < screenWidth) screenWidth = position + size;

      // if the offset pulls the last button away from the right side limit, we reduce that movement so the last button is stuck to the right side limit
      if (position + size - offset < screenWidth) {
        offset = position + size - screenWidth;
      }
    }

    // scroll the calculated amount
    _scrollController.animateTo(offset + _scrollController.offset,
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: widget.duration),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried any of these package?
https://pub.dev/packages?q=carousel

Comment: I can't find the one that adresses that dots issue @ASADHAMEED

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the children on `ListView` widget. You can do this

```
  Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, //make children centered if children is below minimum height or width of its parent
      children: [],
    ),
  )
```